# Runtime error with rust-slack: index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0

Tags: curl, rust, runtime-error

I'm using [rust-slack](https://github.com/frostly/rust-slack) and I have encountered a runtime error, which is hard to understand for a beginner like me:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', ../src/libcollections/vec.rs:1265
stack backtrace:
   1:     0x55c042e567e9 - std::sys::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::h00e948915d1e4c72
   2:     0x55c042e5d9fc - std::panicking::default_hook::_{{closure}}::h7b8a142818383fb8
   3:     0x55c042e5cc49 - std::panicking::default_hook::h41cf296f654245d7
   4:     0x55c042e5d338 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h4cbd7ca63ce1aee9
   5:     0x55c042e5d192 - std::panicking::begin_panic::h93672d0313d5e8e9
   6:     0x55c042e5d100 - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt::hd0daa02942245d81
   7:     0x55c042e5d081 - rust_begin_unwind
   8:     0x55c042e936df - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hbfc935564d134c1b
   9:     0x55c042e93683 - core::panicking::panic_bounds_check::h08d619adcd972898
  10:     0x55c042e1f3db - curl::easy::Easy::cvt::h8b0cee78a8555d56
  11:     0x55c042e1f1fd - curl::easy::Easy::setopt_path::h97000cc95ffaf29e
  12:     0x55c042e20e05 - curl::easy::default_configure::h81b9c3a40aadad76
  13:     0x55c042e1e715 - curl::easy::Easy::new::h6256decf6c19f143
  14:     0x55c042db16e4 - slack_hook::slack::Slack::send::h14b50e23bd1ee165
  15:     0x55c042dab5af - deployer::main::had2f8b13f079aa74
  16:     0x55c042e654e6 - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  17:     0x55c042e5c3c2 - std::rt::lang_start::h53bf99b0829cc03c
  18:     0x7f176846682f - __libc_start_main
  19:     0x55c042da5e98 - _start
  20:                0x0 - <unknown>
```

- It compiles and works on macOS (no panic).
- It compiles but *fails* (see error above) on an almost fresh Ubuntu 16.04.

I have some `println!` traces in my application so I know where it crashes and the 20th line of backtrace seems to say it's here too. Ironically, the function is called `success`, and is the last step of a long script:

```
fn success()  {
    let slack = Slack::new("https://hooks.slack.com/MY_HOOK_URL").unwrap();
    let p = PayloadBuilder::new()
        .text("Deployment success.")
        .channel("#app-notifier")
        .username("Deploy Bot")
        .icon_emoji(":tropical_drink:")
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let res = slack.send(&p);
    match res {
        Ok(()) => println!("Success msg sent."),
        Err(x) => println!("<!> Success error ^^: {:?}",x)
    }
}
```

The Slack URL works on my local machine. How to fix this particular case myself? I just need some clues.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is here: the title seems to imply that you do not understand that using the index 0 on a collection of size 0 will cause a panic... however the questions seems mostly about explaining WHY this index 0 appears here. I would suggest editing the title to make it about `slack` since that's the core of the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thank you! You are right, I have just edited it. Is it better now?

Comment: Great, looks much better now :) Though of course now I've got no idea what the problem is :x

Comment: Apparently this problem (or at least a sub-problem) is fixed now: [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/issues/130#event-822840505).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in curl-rust. Fixed in [this issue](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/issues/130). I just had to run `cargo update`, then rebuild and everything is OK now.

*Thanks to Lukas Kalbertodt, Alex Crichton and the author of rust-slack for their help.*